# List of Jetty9 modules

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

Is there a list of available Jetty 9 modules somewhere?
Just a simple table "this is the name, this is what it does, and here are links" type.

I have searched the Eclipse site and used search engines for some time now, without any usable result. Is it really that much of a secret what jetty modules exist, and what they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command line.

```sh
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar --list-modules
```

Some modules are dynamic/virtual (dependent on your environment).
Some are 3rd party (jsp, jolokia, gcloud, etc).
Of the remaining few, you have the module information itself.

IE: `rewrite` is the rewrite behaviors in doc, `http` is the http server connector, etc.

Going from module to doc is a 1::n scenario, while going from doc to module is a 1::1 scenario.

If you want to know what they do, look at the module definition - (aka `${jetty.home}/modules/${name}.mod`

- They might have properties (documented in module)
- They might have libs (obvious in module)
- They might have xml (see standard XML configuration behaviors in Jetty doc)
- They might have a non-Eclipse license (documented in module)
- They might have a dependent module (documented in module)

The result of enabling a module is simply a command line along the lines of `--module=http`.

The combination of enabled modules (via the combination of ini files) is a longer command line + server classpath + xml load order.

You can see this via ...

```
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-home/start.jar --list-config
```

Comment: It's a good start, since it lists the modules and gives a small explanation. Basically, 2 out of 3 columns. There does not seem to be an --verbose option, though, giving more information about the modules/linking to their respective documentation or project pages. Or did I miss that one as well?

Comment: answer has more detail

Comment: Thank you for adding the details. I think it is generally helpful now.